# How do I rename Company field and remove Address2 field in a multiple value field in Addressfield module

Tags: 7, entities

I was able to remove the Address field with hook alter when it's single value field but don't know how to do it when it's a multiple value field. Same with renaming the fields. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There's a [patch for this](http://drupal.org/node/1010314) in the Addressfield issues queue but it's still under discussion and doesn't work with the latest dev.  You could look at the code in the patch though; it may provide you with insight on how to do what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have read the thread and it looks like it may take more time to do that than use hook alter.